# Nested Route New object creation does not complete if loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I currently have review model that will allow a user to create reviews for a tea model. The user who creates the review can edit or delete the review. I have a nested route within teas that allows you to create a new review for teas as you are viewing all reviews for that specific tea. Currently the nested new route does not allow creation as well as a google authenticated user can not create a review. Below is my controller action and view. I am not experiencing any error it just appears to rollback the database and follow the else logic and render the new page again.

[image: Terminal actions]

```
Model
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tea


  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :rating, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than: 11}

  validates :tea, uniqueness: {scope: :user, message: "has already been reviewed by you" }

  scope :order_by_rating, ->{left_joins(:reviews).group(:id).order('avg(rating) desc')}


end
```

```
Controller Action
      def create
        @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
        if @review.valid?
          @review.save
          redirect_to new_review_path(@review)
        else
          render :new
        end
      end
```

```
View
<%= form_for Review.new do |f|%>
    <% if params[:tea_id] %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :tea_id %>
    <% else %>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :tea_id, "Select a Tea Blend" %>
        <%= f.collection_select :tea_id, Tea.alpha, :id, :flavor_and_brand, include_blank: true %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :rating %>
        <%= f.number_field :rating, min:0, max:10 %>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div> 
    <br>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :content  %>
        <br>
        <%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x25" %>
    </div> 
    <br>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How does the log entry for that request look like?

Comment: In the `else` block can you check what are `@review.errors.full_messages`?

Comment: I'm sorry I am still learning rails how would I go about doing either of those things I am assuming you want me to go into byebug and type in @review.errors.full_messages  ? I have added a picture of what my terminal output is saying.

Comment: So I believe I understand what my issue is the nested version of the form does not have or is not passing in the Tea Flavor. I just have to see how to pass in that parameter I believe to get it to work. Just not sure of what needs to be done in the view to have the Tea Flavor present.

Comment: What does the review_params method look like?

Comment: The current issue now is to complete the action my controller is missing the required key [:id] in my set_review method because it no longer knows what the redirect_to review_path if !@review is or where I should say.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer was that I did not include create in my before action. This is what was causing my set_tea to not be automatically done as a before action.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is by defining a nested route and setting up the form so that it posts to that route. So instead of creating a single form where the user has to select the tea you create a form on the show page or by each tea in a index page where the user can create reviews.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :teas do
  resources :reviews, shallow: true
end
```

`shallow: true` makes it so that the member actions (show, edit, update, destroy) are not nested.

Then setup a partial for the form so that you can reuse it:

```
# app/views/reviews/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for([local_assigns(:tea), review]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rating %>
    <%= f.number_field :rating, min:0, max:10 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content  %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x25" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

By passing an array you get the nested route as the action attribute (`/teas/1/reviews`) and don't have to monkey around with a hidden input. `local_assigns(:tea)` avoids a NoMethodError if its not passed to the partial. The array is compacted so that this partial will work for both creating and updating.

```
# app/views/reviews/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'form', tea: @tea, review: @review >
```

```
# app/views/reviews/edit.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'form', review: @review >
```

```
# app/views/teas/show.html.erb
<h2>Review this tea</h2>
<%= render partial: 'reviews/form', tea: @tea, review: @tea.reviews.new >
```

In the controller you can just fetch the tea from `params[:tea_id]` since you passed it in the path.

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tea, only: [:new, :index, :create]
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /teas/1/reviews
  def create
    # creating the review off the tea reveals intent better than doing
    # it off the user
    @review = @tea.reviews.new(review_params) do |r|
      r.user = current_user
    end
    # Always check if the record is actually persisted 
    # - not just if the applications validations pass!
    if @review.save
      # you could also redirect to the review but this makes more 
      # sense from a ux perspective
      redirect_to @tea, notice: 'Thank you for your review'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # GET /reviews/:id/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PUT|PATCH /reviews/:id
  def update
    if @review.update(review_params)
      redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def set_tea
    @tea = Tea.find(params[:tea_id])
  end

  def set_review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :title)
  end
end
```